# $H^i_I(M)$ is finitely generated iff the support of $Ext^{d-i}_S(M, S)$ has dimension zero

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, krull-dimension, local-cohomology, local-rings

$(R,m)$ is a local Noetherian ring. $M$ is a finite $R$-module.
[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193561/finiteness-dimension), using dualizing complex, *Karl Schwede* says that if $R=S/I$ where $S$ is regular of dimension $d$, then we have: "**$H^i_m(M)$ is finitely generated** iff **the support of $Ext^{d-i}_S(M, S)$  has dimension zero**".

> **Question:** can one prove this, *Not using dualizing complex*

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is Gorenstein, $R=S/I$, and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module, then $$H^i_{\mathfrak m}(M)\simeq\operatorname{Hom}_R(\operatorname{Ext}^{d-i}_S(M, S),E_R(R/\mathfrak m)).$$ (This is the Local Duality Theorem; see Brodmann and Sharp, *Local Cohomology*, Theorem 11.2.6.)
Then use the Matlis duality; see Bruns and Herzog, *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*, Theorem 3.2.13.

Comment: Bruns and Herzog, Theorem 3.2.13 assume that R is complete local ring. in this case R is homomorphic image of regular ring.  +1

Comment: No need to worry about this. One can take the completions of all objects we are working with and nothing is lost.